# SQL calculates total down time minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, summary, gaps-and-islands

I'm working on a down time management system that is capable of saving support tickets for problems in a database, my database has the following columns:

```
-ID
-DateOpen
-DateClosed
-Total
```

I want to obtain the sum of minutes in a day, taking into account that the tickets can be simultaneous, for example:

```
ID    |     DateOpen                    |        DateClosed       | Total 
1          2019-04-01 08:00:00 AM            2019-04-01 08:45:00    45
2          2019-04-01 08:10:00 AM            2019-04-01 08:20:00    10
3          2019-04-01 09:06:00 AM            2019-04-01 09:07:00    1
4          2019-04-01 09:06:00 AM            2019-04-01 09:41:00    33
```

Someone can helpme with that please!! :c

If I use the query "SUM", it will return 89, but if you see the dates, you will understand that the actual result must be 78 because the tickets 2 and 3 were launched while another ticket was working ...

```
DECLARE @DateOpen date = '2019-04-01'

SELECT AlarmID, DateOpen, DateClosed, TDT FROM AlarmHistory 
WHERE CONVERT(date,DateOpen) = @DateOpen
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is generate a sequence of integers and use that to generate times of the day. Join that sequence of times on between your open and close dates, then count the number of distinct times.

Here is an example that will work with MySQL:

```
 SET @row_num = 0;

 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT time_stamp)
         -- this simulates your dateopen and dateclosed table
   FROM (SELECT '2019-04-01 08:00:00' open_time, '2019-04-01 08:45:00' close_time
         UNION SELECT '2019-04-01 08:10:00', '2019-04-01 08:20:00'
         UNION SELECT '2019-04-01 09:06:00', '2019-04-01 09:07:00'
         UNION SELECT '2019-04-01 09:06:00', '2019-04-01 09:41:00') times_used
   JOIN (
         -- generate sequence of minutes in day
         SELECT TIME(sequence*100) time_stamp
           FROM (
             -- create sequence 1 - 10000
                 SELECT (@row_num:=@row_num + 1) AS sequence
                   FROM {table_with_10k+_records}
                  LIMIT 10000
                ) minutes
         HAVING time_stamp IS NOT NULL
          LIMIT 1440
       ) times ON (time_stamp >= TIME(open_time) AND time_stamp < TIME(close_time));
```

Since you are selecting only distinct times that are found in the result, minutes that overlap will not be counted.

**NOTE: Depending on your database, there may be a better way to go about generating a sequence. MySQL does not have a generate sequence function I did it this way to show the basic idea that can easily be converted to work with whatever database you are using.**

Answer (score 0):

[@drakin8564's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55504469/3122921) adapted for SQL Server which I believe you're using:

```
;WITH Gen AS
(
    SELECT TOP 1440 
           CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(minute, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '00:00:00')) AS t
      FROM sys.all_objects a1
     CROSS
      JOIN sys.all_objects a2
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t)
  FROM incidents inci
  JOIN Gen 
    ON Gen.t >= CONVERT(TIME, inci.DateOpen) 
   AND Gen.t < CONVERT(TIME, inci.DateClosed)
```

Your total for the last record is wrong, says 33 while it's 35, so the query results in 80, not 78.

Comment: If this solves your problem, please accept @drakin8564's answer, not mine. All credit goes to them.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, just as MarcinJ told you, 41 - 6 is 35, not 33. So the answer is 80, not 78.

The following solution would work even if the date parameter is not one day only (1,440 minutes). Say if the date parameter is a month, or even year, this solution would still work.

Live demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/462ac/5

```
-- arranged the opening and closing downtime
with a as 
(
    select 
        DateOpen d, 1 status
    from dt
    union all
    select
        DateClosed, 2
    from dt
)
-- don't compute the downtime from previous date
-- if the current date's status is opened
-- yet the previous status is closed
, downtime_minutes AS
(
    select 
        *, 
        lag(status) over(order by d, status desc) as prev_status,
        case when status = 1 and lag(status) over(order by d, status desc) = 2 then
            null
        else
            datediff(minute, lag(d) over(order by d, status desc), d)
        end as downtime
    from a
)
select sum(downtime) as all_downtime from downtime_minutes;
```

Output:

```
| all_downtime |
|--------------|
|           80 |
```

See how it works:

[image]

It works by computing the downtime from previous downtime. Don't compute downtime if the current date's status is open and the previous date's status is closed, which means the current downtime is a non-overlapping one. Non-overlapping downtime are denoted by null.

For that new downtime opened, its downtime is null initially, downtime will be computed on succeeding dates up to when it is closed.

Can make the code shorter by reversing the condition:

```
-- arranged the opening and closing downtime
with a as 
(
    select 
        DateOpen d, 1 status
    from dt
    union all
    select
        DateClosed, 2
    from dt
    -- order by d. postgres can do this?
)
-- don't compute the downtime from previous date
-- if the current date's status is opened
-- yet the previous status is closed
, downtime_minutes AS
(
    select 
        *, 
        lag(status) over(order by d, status desc) as prev_status,
        case when not ( status = 1 and lag(status) over(order by d, status desc) = 2 ) then
            datediff(minute, lag(d) over(order by d, status desc), d)
        end as downtime
    from a
)
select sum(downtime) from downtime_minutes;
```

Not particularly proud of my original solution: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/462ac/1

---

As for the `status desc` on `order by d, status desc`, if a DateClosed is similar to other downtime's DateOpen, `status desc` will sort the DateClosed first.

For this data where 8:00 is present on both DateOpened and DateClosed:

```
INSERT INTO dt
    ([ID], [DateOpen], [DateClosed], [Total])
VALUES
    (1, '2019-04-01 07:00:00', '2019-04-01 07:50:00', 50),
    (2, '2019-04-01 07:45:00', '2019-04-01 08:00:00', 15),   
    (3, '2019-04-01 08:00:00', '2019-04-01 08:45:00', 45);
;
```

For similar time (e.g., 8:00), if we will not sort the closing first before the open, then 7:00 will be computed up to 7:50 only, instead of up to 8:00, as 8:00-open's downtime is initially zero. Here's how the open and closed downtimes are arranged and computed if there's no `status desc` for similar date, e.g., 8:00. The total downtime is 95 minutes only, which is wrong. It should be 105 minutes.

[image]

Here's how that will be arranged and computed if we sort the DateClosed first before the DateOpen (by using `status desc`) when they have similar date, e.g., 8:00. The total downtime is 105 minutes, which is correct.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, uses [gaps and islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands) approach. Answer is based on [SQL Time Packing of Islands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24146989/sql-time-packing-of-islands/24147123#24147123)

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/462ac/11

```
with gap_detector as
(
    select 
        DateOpen, DateClosed,                 
        case when 
            lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) is null 
            or lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) < DateOpen 
        then 
            1
        else 
            0 
        end as gap
    from dt              
)
, downtime_grouper as
(
    select 
        DateOpen, DateClosed, 
        sum(gap) over (order by DateOpen) as downtime_group
    from gap_detector
)
 -- group's open and closed detector. then computes the group's downtime
select 
    downtime_group,
    min(DateOpen) as group_date_open, 
    max(DateClosed) as group_date_closed,
    datediff(minute, min(DateOpen), max(DateClosed)) as group_downtime,

    sum(datediff(minute, min(DateOpen), max(DateClosed))) 
        over(order by downtime_group) as downtime_running_total
from downtime_grouper
group by downtime_group
```

Output:

[image]

**How it works**

A DateOpen is the start of the series of downtime if it has no previous downtime (indicated by null `lag(DateClosed)`). A DateOpen is also a start of the series of downtime if it has a gap from the previous downtime's DateClosed.

```
with gap_detector as
(
    select 
        lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) as previous_downtime_date_closed,
        DateOpen, DateClosed,                 
        case when 
            lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) is null 
            or lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) < DateOpen 
        then 
            1
        else 
            0 
        end as gap
    from dt              
)
select *
from gap_detector
order by DateOpen;
```

Output:

[image]

After detecting the gap starters, we do a running total of the gap so we can group downtimes that are contiguous to each other.

```
with gap_detector as
(
    select 
        DateOpen, DateClosed,                 
        case when 
            lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) is null 
            or lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) < DateOpen 
        then 
            1
        else 
            0 
        end as gap
    from dt              
)
select 
   DateOpen, DateClosed, gap, 
   sum(gap) over (order by DateOpen) as downtime_group
from gap_detector
order by DateOpen;
```

[image]

As we can see from the output above, we can now easily detect the downtime group's earliest DateOpen and latest DateClosed by applying `MIN(DateOpen)` and `MAX(DateClosed)` by grouping on downtime_group. On downtime_group 1, we have earliest DateOpen of `08:00` and latest DateClosed of `08:45`. On downtime_group 2, we have earliest DateOpen of `09:06` and latest DateClosed of `9:41`. And from that we can recalculate the correct downtime even if there are simultaneous downtimes.

---

We can make the code shorter by eliminating the detection of null previous downtime (the current row we are evaluating is the firstmost row in the table) by reversing the logic. Instead of detecting the gaps, we detect the islands (contiguous downtimes). Something is contiguous if the previous downtime's DateClosed overlaps the DateOpen of the current downtime, denoted by 0. If it does not overlaps, then it is a gap, denoted by 1.

Here's the query:

Live test: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/462ac/12

```
with gap_detector as
(
    select 
        DateOpen, DateClosed,                 
        case when lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) >= DateOpen 
        then 
            0
        else 
            1 
        end as gap
    from dt              
)
, downtime_grouper as
(
    select 
        DateOpen, DateClosed, 
        sum(gap) over (order by DateOpen) as downtime_group
    from gap_detector
)
 -- group's open and closed detector. then computes the group's downtime
select 
    downtime_group,
    min(DateOpen) as group_date_open, 
    max(DateClosed) as group_date_closed,
    datediff(minute, min(DateOpen), max(DateClosed)) as group_downtime,

    sum(datediff(minute, min(DateOpen), max(DateClosed))) 
        over(order by downtime_group) as downtime_running_total
from downtime_grouper
group by downtime_group
```

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher:

```
iif(lag(DateClosed) over (order by DateOpen) >= DateOpen, 0, 1) as gap
```